# fullpage_api.getActiveSection() in react-fullpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, fullpage.js

someone has used this library, Can you tell me how I can
get the active section, I have searched in the documentation that it has but it is very little and does not mention that method

I already create the issues but I wanted to know if someone from here could help me

Thanks :D

UPDATE : I could solve it
 in the event p in the method onScroll you can get activeSection with p.activeSection

```
class Two extends React {
 constructor() {
  super();
this.state = {
  initialActiveSection: null
};
}
onScroll(p) {
  if (this.state.initialActiveSection === null)
   this.setState(() => ({ initialActiveSection: p.activeSection 
   }));
}
render() {
 const { initialActiveSection } = this.state;
return (
  <SectionsContainer
    {...options}
    activeSection={initialActiveSection}
    scrollCallback={this.onScroll}
  />
  );
 }
}
```